# Cant delete row from database

Tags: php, html

I have a form that brings in content from a database and I want the user to be able to select a student and delete it from the database.
I get a error saying UNDEFINED INDEX.
I am new to php. Thanks in advance for any help
here is my code

```
  <section> 
                    <form action="include/borrar2.php" method="post">
                    <center>
                        <?php
                            $sql="select * from registro";
                            $res=mysql_query($sql);
                            echo "<table border='1' class='tabla'>";
                            echo"<thead>";
                            echo"<tr>";     

                                echo"<th class='op'>"."ID"."</th>";
                                echo"<th class='op'>"."Detalle"."</th>";
                                echo"<th class='op'>"."Costo"."</th>";
                                echo"<th class='op'>"."&nbsp;"."</th>";
                                echo"<th class='op'>"."&nbsp;"."</th>";                                                         
                            echo"</tr>";
                        echo"</thead>";
                            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                                echo "<tr>";                                
                                echo "<td name='id'>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['detalle']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['costo']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class='opcionT op' >"."<a href=''>"."<input type='submit' value='Actualizar'  class='btn2'>"."</a>"."</td>";
                                echo "<td class='opcionT op' >"."<a href=''>"."<input type='submit' value='Eliminar' name="eliminar" class='btn2'>"."</a>"."</td>";                                                             
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";

                        ?>  
                    </center>
                </form>
                </section>
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST['eliminar'])) {
    $idrow = $_POST['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM `agenda` WHERE `id` = $idrow";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if($res){
    echo '<script>alert("Datos Registrados..")</script>';
    echo "<script>location.href='../index.php'</script>";
}else{
    echo "Error :(" ;
}
}
```

Comment: please provide the full error;  typically those will state which row.

Comment: This is a strange piece of script/html: `"<a href=''>"."<input type='submit' value='Actualizar'  class='btn2'>"."</a>"`. You shouldn't need the `<a>` wrapper.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\academiasweb\ejercicio11\include\borrar2.php on line 5    line 5 is  $idrow = $_POST['id'];

Comment: You aren't posting the `id`. You can **not** put it in a `<td>`. It needs to be a form input - `<input name="id"...`. You're best to use the `hidden` type. Yet you'll have an issue because the last input will overwrite the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass the `id` via a `td` element. That won't work.

```
echo "<td name='id'>".$row['id']."</td>";
```

You need to put it in a form element, even if that element is hidden.

I'd suggest that you use a `GET` approach to this instead. By passing the id to your deleting php script:

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}'>Delete this Student</a>";
```

Then in your php script, you'd just change to use the `$_GET['id']`:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $idrow = intval($_GET['id']);
    $sql="DELETE FROM `agenda` WHERE `id` = $idrow";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    if($res){
        echo '<script>alert("Datos Registrados..")</script>';
        echo "<script>location.href='../index.php'</script>";
    }else{
        echo "Error :(" ;
    }
}
```

I know you're new to PHP, but you'd be best to look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) when running SQL queries, especially `DELETE`, due to the fact that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and insecure.

Comment: Also look into sanitizing your input if you are going to use $_GET within any type of SQL queries.